# apt-get update, updated script condition

Tags: debian, apt

I want apt-get update to direct a script to direct it to reboot a system. I want a system to run apt-get update, if there are updates reboot. This is to keep a simple system updated. The answer might be a little complicated, and I can't seem to get started figuring this out.

System runs Debian Wheezy. It is at defaults with one human user running scripts and rsync on it. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 2):

Use the unattended-upgrades package for apt. There's an option to reboot if necessary:

```
// Automatically reboot *WITHOUT CONFIRMATION*
//  if the file /var/run/reboot-required is found after the upgrade
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";
// If automatic reboot is enabled and needed, reboot at the specific
// time instead of immediately
//  Default: "now"
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "02:00";
```

For a nice writeup, see: http://linux-audit.com/using-unattended-upgrades-on-debian-and-ubuntu/